# Updating detached entity without the primary key

Tags: api, jpa

Suppose that I have a table RESOURCE with the following columns:

*id*: autoincrement value

*name*: the unique name of the resource

*description*: an additional column.

In my business logic, I do not want to know anything about the "id". The client of the API should be able to specify just the unique name and the description.

When I receive the resource in my controller, I only know the name and the description. I can map this to a partial instance of the JPA entity (because I do not know the id).

What's the best way to save the received resource?

Suppose that Resource is the model of the resource in my business layer (the APIs), and suppose that ResourceEntity is the JPA model of the resource. Resource does not have the field "id", ResourceEntity does.

I am thinking to use something like:

```
/* Parse the posted json to create an instance of Resource. */
Resource resource = parseRequestJson();

/* Map the Resource instance to a ResourceEntity instance. It can be easily implemented by MapStruct */
ResourceEntity resourceEntity = mapper.toResourceEntity(resource); 

/* Load the resource from the database */
ResourceEntity loadedResourceEntity = resourceRepository.findByName(resource.getName());

/* At this point resourceEntity has a null id and loadedResourceEntity does not have the posted changes. */

/* Set the id */
resourceEntity.setId(loadedResourceEntity.getId());

/* Save the udpated entity */
resourceRepository.save(resourceEntity);
```

Are there better ways to do it?